# How does Clark Kent get his job at The Daily Planet in Man of Steel?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

How does Clark Kent get his job at The Daily Planet in Man of Steel?

While there might be a lot in those "lost years" that we are not shown on screen, it seems that he has spent a lot of time wandering around changing from one job to another (we see him working as a fisherman or waiter). It’s also made clear that he wanted to go unnoticed in school. Although Man of Steel neither says that he did nor did not pursue higher education, why would someone who wants to go unnoticed go to college, then start chaining all these jobs with a fake identity? Given that curriculum and with no degree, how would he make it through the hiring process at The Planet?

On the other hand, he seems to be quite skilled at getting a job, even with a fake ID — he got that job with the military contractors, no less, when they were digging the spaceship out of the ice. So, maybe he faked his qualifications and past employment history.

Maybe Lois Lane had something to do in the whole process (although I seem to recall that Perry introduces them to one another, so it’s likely they were pretending they did not know each other beforehand).

Are there any "official" sources (novelization of the movie, movie scripts, articles or interview with actors/director/writers of the movie...) that explains how Clark Kent gets his job at The Daily Planet?

Comment: Easy, threaten Perry with violence until he is given a job, and then Super-Kiss the memory of it away - sorted!

Comment: After what happened to Metropolis in that movie, I assume there were plenty of job openings, especially for the kinds of people that tend to run towards the explosions rather than away from them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Clark was hired as a freelance "stringer"...

Clark gets his job at the Daily Planet at the very end of *Man of Steel*, after Lois already knows he is Superman:

> **MARTHA KENT:** What are you going to do when you're not saving the world? Have you given any thought to that?
>
> **CLARK KENT:** I have, actually. I gotta find a job...where I can keep my ear to the ground. Where people won't look twice when I want to go somewhere dangerous and start asking questions.

Less than a minute later, the film cuts to Perry introducing Clark to Lombard and Lois at the Planet.  Perry refers to Clark as a new "stringer", meaning a paid-per-piece freelancer.  A stringer isn't on the payroll, and so there is no financial commitment involved in hiring one — he only gets paid if the work is good enough for print.  As such, qualifications would not be a big deal.  A simple portfolio with a few well-written pieces would be enough.

Comment: "*“Lane, Lombard,” Perry called out. Lois noted absently that he had somebody with him. Focused on her story, she vaguely registered the presence of a tall, dark-haired guy wheeling a bike into the office. “I want to introduce you to our new stringer. I was hoping you could show him the ropes.”*" - Novelisation

Comment: So... no health benefits, eh?

Answer (score -2):

Clark was shown to read Plato at early age so it provided a clue that he is knowledgeable. so getting a job at the Daily Planet isn't that hard especially for getting a job as a stringer. Or as a freelancer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  The question was specifically asking for canonical sources, so you should provide some evidence from the movie, its novelization, or statements from the creators that explain how Clark Kent got hired.

Comment: Deep knowledge of philosophy: solid gold in job interviews, obviously. Employers love someone who can debate every decision for seventeen hours.